# Not triggering sales_order_place_after observer

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create a observer which should trigger after sales order complete.
Unfortunately,its not firing.
my Sales_registration.xml file :

true
            local
        
    

 Config.xml file
[image]
[image: Observer.phml]
Observer.phml

Comment: Well you're observing `checkout_submit_all_after`, shouldn't you observe `sales_order_place_after` ?

Comment: Why is there a global tag outside of the config node in the xml?

Comment: That I changed ....Still not triggering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config.xml file code as below

**app/code/local/Sales/Registration/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sales_Registration>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sales_Registration>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <salesregistration>
        <class>Sales_Registration_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>salesregistration_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </salesregistration>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>salesregistration/observer</class>
            <method>getAlert</method>
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php code as below

**app/code/local/Sales/Registration/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Sales_Registration_Model_Observer
{
    public function getAlert(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
        $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
        $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
        $customerName = $customerData->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: still Not trigerring

Comment: Have you enabled module in app/etc/modules/Sales_Registration.xml ?

Comment: Yes...enable though Sales_Registration.xml

Comment: <config>
    <modules>
        <Sales_Registration>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sales_Registration>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: How do you check it not triggering?

Comment: public function getAlert(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
  Mage::log('helllllllo');
 }

Comment: after purchase complete, it should trigger right?

Comment: In another namespace there is a same module name.is it effect the execution.

Comment: Yes after all submitting it will trigger. I suggest you can also use sales_place_order_after

Comment: I mean, Pan/Registration and Sale/Registration

Comment: Yes so it conflict with Pan_Register you need to change your group name register to another

Comment: I have updated code use it will solve your problem

Comment: Still Not triggering...

Comment: Updated code with sales_order_place_after event try with this

Comment: Now unable to complete the order showing error.like  The requested quantity for "LUCABELLA DINING TABLE 220X100" is not available.

Comment: stock is available

Comment: Whats your observer code post in your question

Comment: <?php

class Sales_Registration_Model_Observer
{
  
   
  public function getAlert(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
  Mage::log('xmlData');
  echo "kfjkldfjldfldfdgfd";
  exit;
  
  
   }
}

Comment: from observer i need to get order details

Comment: Updated code. you can get order information using updated code

Comment: still its not triggering.....

Comment: now unable to complete the order....once we place the order it will refresh the page and stay in same page only.if we clicking again on  "place order" button it showing empty cart

Comment: remove exit from observer and check in log file.it will trigger

Comment: Now Its Triggering....... lot of thanks......

Comment: If it helps you can mark it as accepted and upvote it.